# ¿Por qué me desaparecen puntos, pero no me indica qué ha pasado?

Tags: soporte, reputación

soy nuevo aquí y me ha sorprendido que un par de veces me ha dicho la página que tengo una cantidad x de puntos, y al rato esa cantidad se ve reducida, pero no he recibido ningún punto negativo... ¿A qué se puede deber?

Comment: ¿Cuándo te pasó? ¿Podrías dar más datos?

Comment: Ayer, un par de veces, no podría especificar más que eso, tenía 187 puntos y al rato tenia 160 pero no había notificaciones explicando por qué, ni puntos negativos.

Comment: Puedes auditar tu reputación entrando en https://es.stackoverflow.com/reputation. Allí se ve todo. Ahora bien, desde hace un tiempo ya no es posible ver el historial de aceptaciones/desaceptaciones de una pregunta, que seguramente es el problema en este caso. La hipótesis de eferion me convence bastante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplemente alguien te ha quitado un punto positivo. Si alguien te vota positivo y después te retira el voto (ambas acciones dentro del mismo día) te quedas como estás, sin sumar ni restar ninguno.

Esta variación fantasma de puntos también se puede ver reflejada si:

- Alguien Te vota negativo y después retira el voto
- Marcan tu respuesta como solución y después retiran dicha marca

Eso sí, es importante matizarlo bien. Ambas acciones tienen que realizarse **el mismo día**. Si se realizan en días diferentes se registrarán ambas acciones (una suma de puntos y después una resta o al revés)

Comment: Va, gracias. Pensaba que la plataforma notificaba ese tipo de cambios. Duda Resuelta :)

Comment: Cuando me deje aceptar la pregunta lo hago xD que tengo que esperar por lo que se ve

Comment: @enriquemanzanogil No tengas tanta prisa, deja que otros con más conocimientos se pasen por la pregunta y te den su versión, que lo mismo es más elaborada y certera que la mía (o simplemente te gusta más)